# Connecting two android with BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to connect two anonymouse android device  (without identity sharing) with bluetooth low energy?
I am trying to make an application which allows content sharing  at small crowded location.I dont think P2P Wifi is suitable for me since it drains lots of battery power.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only profile supported by BLE in Android L preview seems to be the GATT profile. You can get small objects over BLE connection between two anonymous devices, but a socket-like interface is not supported.

Comment: does that "small" objects include device name and andress?

Comment: Yeah, device name and address can be very well supported by the GATT server.

Answer (score 0):

Android L release has added Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral role.

In BLE a connection can only be between 1 Central and 1 Peripheral.

This works fine on Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 with Android L preview.

The throughput of BLE is not very high compared to Bluetooth Classic and Wifi direct.

Comment: so basically i can not use BLE for annonymouse contacts between 2 device?

Comment: Yes, you can, but between Android devices you'll have to wait for the next version of Android.  Android 4.4 and below only support the Central mode. 

Right now the L Developer Preview BLE peripheral mode works great on the Nexus 5 but there are reports that it doesn't work on the Nexus 7.

Comment: In fact it currently doesn't work on the Nexus 7:
http://developer.android.com/preview/support.html
(first bullet under Wireless and Connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that BLE was intended to send teaspoon sized data not a firehose like classic bluetooth.  Packet size about 20 bytes.  You can of course send more than one packet.